# about block XTEA in C code

Tags: endianness, block-cipher

i want to send/receive  encryption data with differnet endian systems
it is possible?
i heard that that is possible to same endian  systems
xxtea code is block xtea in internet...

```
#define MXA (((z>>5^y<<2) + (y>>3^z<<4)) ^ ((sum^y) + (xt_keyA[(p&3)^e] ^ z)))
void Encode(unsigned long *encode_data, unsigned char dataLength) 
{
unsigned long y, z,sum;
unsigned long p, e,round;
dataLength=0;
round = 10;


sum = 0;
z = encode_data[1];

do {
   sum += 0x12345678;
   e = (sum >> 2) & 3;
   for (p=0; p< 1; p++) 
   {
     y = encode_data[p+1]; 
     z = encode_data[p] += MXA;
   }
   y = encode_data[0];
   z = encode_data[1] += MXA;

  } while (--round);

}

void DecodeA(unsigned long *decode_data, unsigned char dataLength) 
{
unsigned long y, z,sum;
unsigned  long p, e;
dataLength=0;

sum = 10*0x12345678;
y = decode_data[0];
do {
   e = (sum >> 2) & 3;
   for (p=1; p>0; p--) 
   {
     z = decode_data[p-1];
     y = decode_data[p] -= MXA;
   }
   z = decode_data[1];
   y = decode_data[0] -= MXA;
  } while ((sum -= 0x12345678) != 0);

}
```